# Why can I not generate a valid oauth-token using command-line curl for the LinkedIn API?

Tags: curl, oauth, meteor, linkedin-api

When testing the LinkedIn API and attempting to build a Meteor JS smart package to authenticate against LinkedIn's OAuth provider, I've run upon a total roadblock.

In following [these directions](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#), I was able to successfully generate an `oauth_token` for use in an authorization request, in the form of:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={oauth_token}
```

When putting that into the browser with the token generated by a ruby script that looks like this:

```
require 'oauth'

api_key = '{linkedin api key}'
api_secret = '{linkedin api secret}'

configuration = { :site => 'https://api.linkedin.com',
                          :authorize_path => '/uas/oauth/authenticate',
                          :request_token_path => '/uas/oauth/requestToken',
                          :access_token_path => '/uas/oauth/accessToken' }

consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(api_key, api_secret, configuration)

request_token = consumer.get_request_token
puts request_token.params[:oauth_token]
```

I can then easily dump the token as a querystring param in the browser, using the above URI, and see the LinkedIn permissions dialog.

The LinkedIn auth window that gets displayed with a valid token:
[image]

Unfortunately, when attempting to write a curl request in the command line, the `oauth_token` that is generated fails when used in that same url. Indeed, it results in linkedin responding with a 500 error, and the browser showing a standard 500 error window. The response comes with no additional details:

[image: 500 error]

Here's the code that is similar to what I had implemented in my curl request to linkedin for a new `oauth_token`:

```
alex@alex-mac accounts-linkedin (fixes_for_meteor_0_5_4)* $ cat linkedin_oauth_gen.sh 

curl -X POST https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken --verbose --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="0d9a3e40660811e2bcfd0800200c9a66",oauth_timestamp="1359019570",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_consumer_key="{oauth_consumer_key}",oauth_signature="{oauth_signature}"'
```

It's worth noting that that I had used [LinkedIn's OAuth test console](https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console#) to generate the Authorization header.

This is important, because I get the same problem when attempting to implement similar functionality within my Meteor JS smart package.

My main question, however, is why in the world I can do it with the ruby code above, but when using a simple curl shell command, the token does not seem to be validly generated (or LinkedIn simply does not want to honor it)...

Comment: FWIW, I've read through this in detail: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/common-issues-oauth-authentication

Comment: I've also found this thread in linkedin developer forums:
http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/500-internal-server-error-when-authorizing-user#comment-21135

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, the devil is in the tiniest of details.

In solving this problem, I used the ever wonderful [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to spy on the requests that my ruby script was making via the oauth library.

As it turned out there were **two** distinct issues with how I was attempting to make requests from curl and from meteor that I discovered by spying on the successful ruby request while looking back at my code and messing with the `oauth_callback` Authorization header parameter to reverse engineer the problem.

Either one of these issues, or in combination, caused an invalid and unrecognizable oauth token to be generated. Instead of returning a 401, linkedin generated a token! Alas, this token was useless.

Here are 2 distinct request authorization headers that fail (with reasons after each):

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_body_hash="2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYkK%2FYBwk%3D", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F_oauth%2Flinkedin%3Fclose", oauth_consumer_key="*********", oauth_nonce="SJ3DSTHLh0T4UcqzYOUOqubIeWN9FERCePm5ro35EY", oauth_signature="*********", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1359081520", oauth_version="1.0"
```

In this first example, the problem is that the `oauth_callback` param has a malformed querystring param. It turns out that having a query string param like `?close` without a value, as in `?close=true`, causes the request to be completely fubared. I still don't know exactly why, but that seems to be the case.

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_body_hash="2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYkK%2FYBwk%3D", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F_oauth%2Flinkedin%3Fclose", oauth_consumer_key="*********", oauth_nonce="SJ3DSTHLh0T4UcqzYOUOqubIeWN9FERCePm5ro35EY", oauth_signature="*********", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1359081520", oauth_version="1.0"
```

In this second example, the problem is that `oauth_callback` has `localhost` in its domain. It turns out that some oauth providers, linkedin being one of, don't like host names in the `oauth_callback` param (vs FQDN or IP addresses). Beats me why. We need to use `127.0.0.1`. There's no good reason, but it just **is**. Lame, but true.

**This one works:**

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_body_hash="2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYkK%2FYBwk%3D", oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2F_oauth%2Flinkedin%3Fclose%3Dtrue%26state%3D0e314d0d-a5ca-40ca-8fcd-caa1cfce3ed4", oauth_consumer_key="*********", oauth_nonce="0KBnMSMI8NNk1cXn0YyTRpUnPdnqAX7F06KEloh9bs", oauth_signature="*********", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1359082177", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Note: I've replaced `oauth_consumer_key` and `oauth_signature` values with `*********` for obvious reasons of protecting my keys and removing the possibility of reverse engineering of my secret.